# How can I disable automatic monitor switching on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, display

I have monitor setup with a hardware switch between my Xbox and my Netbook.

On XP, switching between these is easy; I just flick the switch and it changes. My netbook's monitor doesn't turn on; it just stays off like it should.

On Windows 7, switching the monitor to Xbox causes Windows 7 to re-enable my netbook's built-in monitor, messing with my resolution and causing headaches.

How can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: Apparently you can't disable it. See this [page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/kvm-switch-windows-7-creates-monitor-switching/84f41660-1933-4109-9b13-1ea8a1c27be7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible from Windows 7 upward.

Answer (score 0):

There are BIOS settings to control display switching. The settings vary by brand and version, but usually would be something along the lines of "automatic swithing" and can be enabled or disabled.

Comment: If this was the case, then my monitor would have switched on XP. It didn't, so this is not the case. Please read the question fully.